# In the config function inside state how to use factory /service for the custom data properties in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-route

In the below example I have to use service inside roles how to use service and return array value from there

Example :

```
 .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $rootScope) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('signin');
    $stateProvider.state('site', {
        'abstract': true,
        resolve: {
            authorize: ['authorization', function (authorization) {
                return authorization.authorize();
            }, ]
        }
    })
    .state('signin', {
        parent: 'site',
        url: '/signin',
        data: {
            roles: (function () {
                //principal.GetRoles(); --> in the below line i am returning hardcoded array value but i have take that array value from below principle factory 
                return ['Dev','Admin'];
            })()
        },
        views: {
            '': { templateUrl: '/signin.html' },
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: '/index.html',
                controller: 'SigninCtrl'
            }
        },
    })}
])
```

Service / Factory :- from here i need to `return array` to the above custom object  data->roles that inside `signin` state

Below Example:-

```
.factory('principal', ['$q', '$http', '$timeout', '$cookieStore', '$cookies', function ($q, $http, $timeout, $cookieStore, $cookies) {
var _identity = undefined,
  _authenticated = false;

return {
    isIdentityResolved: function () {
        return angular.isDefined(_identity);
    },
    isAuthenticated: function () {
        return _authenticated;
    },
    RedirectUrl: function (absUrl) {
        $cookieStore.put('RedirectUrl', absUrl);
        return true;
    },

    GetRoles: function () {
        return ['Dev','Admin']
    },
 }
])
```

Comment: You need to add dependency to Your `principal` factory...

Comment: if am adding `principal` to the config function then  also i am not able to call the services inside data objects

Answer (score 0):

With this solution (random example!), you will need to inject these dependencies into your controller. One of those dependencies is your service! From there, you can call any method that you have defined in your Service (SomeService.getSomeArray()). In your case, the service method is calling the API that will correlate with the array that you are looking for. Injecting your service in your controller will allow you to manipulate the data whichever way is needed.

```
 angular.module('dashboard.services.Transaction', [
      'dashboard.Config',
      'dashboard.Utils',
      'dashboard.services.GeneralModel'
])
```

These will be built in or custom dependences, which you can add to your module

Make sure to handle injection of dependencies

```
.service('TransactionService', function(GeneralModelService, otherDependencies ) {
  var self = this;

  this.getPaymentInfo = function(id, callback) {
    // API callback which is calling your back end api, your params are whatever params
    // your remote method expects
  };
});
```